# How to get around PowerCLI Connect-VIServer

Tags: powershell, vmware, vmware-server, powercli

I am pretty new to using PowerCLI and I would like to use it to automate a couple of things, but it does not seem to allow me to run what I want to without connecting to a server. I do not want to have to connect to a server to automate the service I am trying to run. Would anyone have any ideas on how to work around the `Connect-VIServer` issue?

If it helps I am trying to use the `Set-Template` command to convert my file to a VM.

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't own a copy of `vCenter` you can still get a lot out of `PowerCLI`. 
`PowerCLI` will enable you to manage multiple `ESX servers` at once even without `vCenter`,
but no ****vMotion*** or **templates***, you still need `vCenter` for those features!

So you can't avoid the use of `connect-viserver`

Comment: Thanks for the response! How would I have to go about using the ESX servers so that I can use the `Set-Template` command in `PowerCLI`?

Comment: To use ‘set-template‘ cmdlet you have to connect to a vCenter Server